# Android RippleForeground bounded mode implementation

Tags: android, graphics, rippledrawable

I'm reading through the implementation of `RippleDrawable` and [RippleForeground](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleForeground.java) (the software rendering part), and I already knew that being bounded means that the ripple has a mask with it.

But I'm still confused on some points of the implementation:

1. Why did the implementation say ["Bounded ripples don't have enter animations"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleForeground.java#165) and simply skip the enter animation for it? How can the ripple animation be started in this case (if user did not release his touch so no exit is fired)?

   ```
   @Override
   protected Animator createSoftwareEnter(boolean fast) {
       // Bounded ripples don't have enter animations.
       if (mIsBounded) {
           return null;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Why did the implementation pick a [nearly constant value](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleForeground.java#98) (and why is that `random()`) for `mBoundedRadius` and [`mTargetRadius`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleForeground.java#224)? What if the view masked with `ColorDrawable` is larger than that size, will it work correctly?

   ```
   public RippleForeground(RippleDrawable owner, Rect bounds, float startingX, float startingY,
           boolean isBounded) {
       ...
       if (isBounded) {
           mBoundedRadius = MAX_BOUNDED_RADIUS * 0.9f
                   + (float) (MAX_BOUNDED_RADIUS * Math.random() * 0.1);
       }
       ...
   }

   ...

   private void computeBoundedTargetValues() {
       ...
       mTargetRadius = mBoundedRadius;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, I've found the answer myself by digging into commit history and trying the new Marshmallow image. The answer is simple:

They removed the (foreground) ripple on touch for bounded `RippleDrawable`, but not for unbounded, leaving this inconsistency deliberately.

I just tested on the Marshmallow image from Android SDK. It is removed, and even worse, they left the exiting ripple in the place user first touched the screen instead of where their finger lifted from the screen.

[image: Ripple on Marshmallow]

I cannot understand this design decision since it seems like a regression much more than an improvement to me, but as in the commit log, they believe they did [implement bounded ripple animation](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/6a67db41388165aca63d0d5de2830cc096ed930b), instead of removing it.

But for the second question, I still haven't got an answer yet.